# How bad is it that I gave full permision for all my /usr/share folders?

Tags: permissions, chmod

By mistake ran `sudo chmod - R a+rwx /usr/share`.

I am the only user of this computer, but I am afraid of viruses and whatnot and 
I have no idea how to return the settings.

Thanks in advance for the advice :)

Comment: To revert, run `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share`. ...and if you really think you are the only user, think again - `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`.

Comment: Thanks, what about the subfolders? Are they all wuth those permisions?

Comment: I don't know about all the subfolders and files. If you've used the `-R` flag, I'd recommend a full backup and a reinstall.